# Pulling JSON body from API Response using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parse-platform

I'm using a parse.com API server which I am successfully communicating with in Javascript using AJAX.

I am writing output from the return into the browser console as follows:

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .fail(function(response){
                        console.log("Fail Return is: " + response);
                        });
```

Within this response is a JSON body containing a message such as follows:

```
{
  "code": 202,
  "error": "Account already exists for this username."
}
```

How would I extract this from the response into say a separate console message?

Comment: `console.log(response.code)` and `console.log(response.error)`?

Comment: You might have to parse the JSON string to get an actual JSON object.  Example:  console.log(JSON.parse(response).code);

Comment: Also you can use window.fetch instead of jquery https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

OK,

After getting help externally, this does the job:

```
console.log("Fail Return is: " + temp.error);
```